# Laravel in production server scheduled jobs dispatches twice

Tags: laravel, queue, supervisord, laravel-jobs, laravel-scheduler

In Laravel 7 I use supervisor in my production server(Ubuntu) to get some jobs running automatically.

in local env everything work well. but in my production server every job queuing twice.

This my command

```
    public function handle()
    {
        dispatch(new JobsCreateStatement());
    }
```

If I do not queue the job and execute immediately there is no issue (only one job executed) like below

```
    public function handle()
    {
        dispatch_now(new JobsCreateStatement());
    }
```

If I dispatch manually a job inside my controller also not an issue (only one job executed)

```
    public function test()
    {
       dispatch(new JobsCreateStatement());
    }
```

This is my job handle method

```
    public function handle()
    {
       Log::info("inside create statement job............"); 
       //Mail::to('myemail@gmail.com')->queue(new MailStatement());
    }
```

This is `Kernel.php`

```
    protected $commands = [
        //.... other commands
        'App\Console\Commands\CreateStatement',
    ];


    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {   
        //...... other commands
        $schedule->command('create:statement')->hourly();
    }
```

This is crontab entry in ubuntu

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/moving/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

This my supervisor configuration

```
[program:queueworker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/moving/artisan queue:listen
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
stderr_logfile=/var/www/html/moving/public/worker_err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/moving/public/worker.log
```

This is the output

```
tingsapp@tingsapp-dev:/var/www/html/moving$ tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log 
[2024-02-05 14:40:04] local.INFO: inside crate statement job............  
[2024-02-05 14:40:05] local.INFO: inside crate statement job............
```

In the output you see that the first one is executed at `2024-02-05 14:40:04` and second one executed at `2024-02-05 14:40:04` same time, but some time the second and first differs `1` second only.

Any help please?

Comment: are you sure the job is not failing the first time? are you sure this is actually the same job, and you are not double dispatching/logging?

Comment: @krisgjika  yes I'm sure the above steps are exactly what I have done. it's almost a week I'm looking for a solution.

this function dispatches twice I don't know what the hell is wrong: 


public function handle()
    {
        dispatch(new JobsCreateStatement());
    }